# Why do empty vessels make more sound?

Tags: acoustics

Why do we hear a roaring or humming sound when an empty bottle is held close to our ear ?

When I hold a flask close to my ears, I hear like a sound which coming from its interior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual way that this phenomenon is described is

> when you hold a sea shell up to your ear, you can hear the sea

What actually happens, according to [this link](http://science.howstuffworks.com/question556.htm), is that the vessel acts as a resonator / reflector for ambient noise - sounds that already present in the environment are amplified and stand out more.

The "you hear your blood" myth is just that - a myth. Although (healthy) human ears *are* exquisitely sensitive... see [my answer to a recent question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/147838/26969) on the subject of just how little air movement can be perceived as noise.

Comment: Testing with bottles of different wall thickness confirmed: I don't know what OP is talking about

Comment: @npst - did you try just cupping your hands and holding them over your ears (without closing off the space completely)? Do that in a slightly noisy environment (some background fans, etc) and you'll hear a rushing sound, most likely.

Comment: Yes, I meant I can't find any difference between different bottles, filled or not when the ear is closed off.